# Single process accessed by multiple apps

Tags: java, c++, spring

I have a single C++ process that performs some extraction. I have 4 Java apps that are dependent on that extraction. How can I make sure that only one app is using that process at a time? Also, I don't want other apps to wait for a long time.

Comment: It would help if you provided more information about these apps. What kind of extraction is it doing? How are the java apps using the c++ app?

Comment: Are you trying to synchronize the C++ app against all 4 Java Apps, or just sync the java apps?

Comment: These java apps consume single C++ app. Basically C++ app is old legacy app that generate text files in different encodings. I am basically trying to find the elegant solution through which we can call this C++ app from these java apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) to setup a worker queue on your C++ process. Then your java apps can post to that queue and you C++ process can do as many or as few extractions as it wants.

There are other queues out there, such as [HornetQ](http://hornetq.jboss.org/) that can do the same as ZeroMQ and might be a bit simpler.

If you want to make it only do 1 extraction at a time, make your C++ thing spawn only one worker, then no matter how much stuff is posted to the Queue by your java apps, only one thing will happen at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Using socketed I/O would allow you to queue up requests.